# Erlang release with rebar: some issues

Tags: erlang, release, rebar

1.
When I'm trying to run my app using:

```
# ./rebar clean compile generate
# rel/master/bin/master console
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
application: app_name
exited:{shutdown,{app_name}, start, [normal, []]}}
type:permanent
{"kernel pid terminated", application_controler, "{application_start_failure,app_name 
..........
```

So I can't start my application.

2.
 Moreover, right after builing release

```
# rel.... start
# rel.... stop
```

Will cause error: "Node master@127.0.0.1 not responding to pings"

While

```
# rel.... stop <- the same error as above
# rel.... start
# rel.... stop <- is fine (outputs "ok")
```

---

**App structure:**

```
deps ebin rebar rebar.config src rel
```

rebar.config

```
{erl_first_files, []}.
{cover_enabled, true}.
{erl_opts, [debug_info]}.
{sub_dirs, ["rel"]}.
{deps_dir, ["deps]}.
{deps, [some_stable_modules_from_github]}.
```

reltool.config (from `rel` folder)

```
{sys, [
     {lib_dirs, ["../..", "../deps"]},
     {rel, "master", "1",
        [app_name, 
         kernel,
         stdlib,
         stdlib,
         sasl,
         some_stable_modules]},
     {rel, "start_clean", "", [kernel, stdlib]},
     {boot_rel, "master"},
     {profile, embedded},
     {excl_sys_filters, ["^bin/.*", "^erts.*/bin/{dialyzer|typer)"])},
     {app, sasl, ["incl_cond", include]},
     {app, hipe, ["incl_cond", exclude]},
     {app, some_stable_module, ["incl_cond", include]},
     {app, master, ["incl_cond", include]}
   ]}.

{target_dir, "master"}.

{overlay, [
          {mkdir, "log/sasl"},
          {copy, "files/erl", "\{\{erts_vsn\}\}/bin/erl"},
          {copy, "files/nodetool", "\{\{erts_vsn\}\}/bin/nodetool"},
          {copy, "files/master", "bin/master"},
          {copy, "files/app.config", "etc/app.config"},
          {copy, "files/vm.args", "etc/vm.args"}
          ]}.
```

Two questions:

1. Why I can start my application using `rel/master/bin/master console`?
2. Why I'm getting "node is not responding to pings" error?

thanks!

PS. In general it's a basic application which is created using rebar. I just added a couple modules to work with mongodb.

Comment: I'm not sure that you are aware that you cut away the actual error message.  It would have helped to see what error you get with regards to app_name.

Answer (score 1):

From your reltool.config, it looks like the app_name application is not included in the release. Please ensure that:

```
{app, app_name, ["incl_cond", include]},
```

is there. If that doesn't help, try to start your application manually. For example:

```
erl -pa ebin deps/whatever/ebin ...
> application:start(app_name).
```

That should give you a hint of what's wrong/missing in the release.

UPDATE: If you cannot start your application manually try and debug it. Assuming that you start a root supervisor in your application module, what happens if you start the supervisor manually? Could you post your .app/.app.src file? The start function from your application module? The eventual start_link function from your supervisor?

**PS:** You have two "stdlib" entries in your reltool.config

Comment: I added `{app, app_name, ["incl_cond", include]},` with the same results. I can start application manually `erl -pa ebin` plus `pplication:start(app_name)` or any other way: the same error.

Comment: btw, as you can see I included in reltool.config actual application release `{app, master, ["incl_cond", include]}`. Master is a node. Is it ok?

Comment: You should add *applications* not node names.  Are all your applications (including dependencies) in your reltool.config?

Comment: @DanielLuna, yes, all of them.

Comment: Did you try manually starting the root supervisor of your application?

Comment: If the `rebar clean compile generate` works, then you have some problem in the startup sequence of your app.  I know that Erlang lacks a *lot* of information when crashing in init.  io:format programming it is... :-)

Comment: @DanielLuna, @ Roberto thanks for your time. I will try to debug it somehow. Erlang is not so easy for newbie.